# Salt: Properties for pillar data?

Tags: saltstack

I would like to have properties (computed attributes) for data from saltstack pillars:

We structure our systems like this:

```
systems:
  - customer: foo 
    project: bar
    stage: p
    ...
  - customer: foo
    project: bar
    stage: q
    ...
```

I would like to compute a variable "system.name" like this: `"{customer}_{project}_{stage}"`.

From the above example I would get these two computes values:

- system.name = "foo_bar_p"
- system.name = "foo_bar_q"

I would be able to access `system.name` just like `system.customer` or `system.project`.

How to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can define properties like you'd like.

However, you can compute this value inside your state file or your template with jinja commands. For example:

```
{% for system in salt['pillar.get']('systems', []) %}
  {% do system.update({'name': system.customer + '_' + system.project + '_' + system.stage}) %}
test_state_for_{{ system.name }}:
  test.configurable_test_state:
    - result: False
    - comment: {{ system }}
{% endfor %}
```

In this example, the `system` dict is updated (merged) with the `name` computed value: `system.customer + '_' + system.project + '_' + system.stage`.

Comment: Yes, your solution should work. Thank you. Still, somehow a solution which looks nicer would be better. I personally like object oriented programming: Properties and inheritance are great and the result looks readable.

Comment: SaltStack is always evolving and something could be proposed. They are very open to suggestions and, even more, to pull requests.

Comment: @ChristopheDrevetDroguet I can not create a pull request, since my current idea is still vague. What is the best place for talking to the developers? After defining "done" I can start to code :-)

Comment: Well, you can open an issue on github, and discuss it here (sometimes it's more of a monologue but it's public, at least). Or to the "users" mailling list or the IRC chat. See https://saltstack.com/community/ for links and information.

Comment: I asked on the mailing list (related, but different topic). Here is the reply: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/salt-users/5Oa48H1QYtk He suggested to use external pillars. See https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/external_pillars.html